# Unable to download a pdf file in a django app?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I've made a django app and there is a file I want user would be able to download on clicking a button. But I'm unabale to download it even though everything seems to be correct.

Here's a section my `index.html`

```
<h3>Download your file here-</h3>
<button>Download
    <a href="/my_website/my_webapp/static/my_webapp/pictures/bill/bill.pdf" download='bill'></a>
</button>
```

On clicking the button the file doesn't get downloaded. Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens when you try to go to that url in your browser? The "/my_website/my_webapp/static/my_webapp/pictures/bill/bill.pdf"

I suspect that it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to write a view to do the download

Comment: I've given the attribute download in anchor tag so the browser doesn't navigate to the path. Also the path is correct because in VS Code when I hover over the path and click on Follow link it actually opens up the bill.pdf, @MatthewGaiser

Comment: Well, I figured it out. Actually the button property was not executing the anchor tag property they weren't performing together. A lone anchor tag was working so I removed the button tag. Poor me!!! Thanks for your time by the way,